# editing a value in a multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, session-variables

I've got a session called `Cart_array` which holds a multidimensional array in the following way:

```
$_SESSION['Cart_array'] = array(
                1 => array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                )
            );
```

this is how items are added to the cart session. `pid` is obtained from another form

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
        $pid    = $_POST['pid'];
        if (!isset($_SESSION['Cart_array']) || count($_SESSION['Cart_array']) < 1) { //check if cart session is not set or empty
            $_SESSION['Cart_array'] = array(
                1 => array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                )
            );
        } else {
                array_push($_SESSION['Cart_array'], array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                ));

        } //end else
    } //end if
```

the user has a form with the following things in a function:

```
     <?php foreach ($_SESSION['Cart_array'] as $eachItem) {
            $itemID = $eachItem['ID'];
            $itemQty = $eachItem['QTY']; >?

        <input class="qty" name="quantity" type="number" value="<?php echo $itemQty;?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="qtyChange<?php echo $itemID;?>" value="Change Qty" />
        <input name="qtyOfItem" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $itemID?>"/> 
}
```

This form will go through the `Cart_array` and display the quantity in the cart for every item.
I want the user to be able to change the quantity in the cart for the specific item that they chose when they click the `Change Qty` button
I'm not sure how to go around doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the array like this

**Your Array**

```
$list = array([0]=>
                   array(
                         [ID]=>'XYZ' 
                         [QTY]=>'1'
                         )
             ); 


    my_function()
   {
    $list=$_SESSION['Cart_array']; 
    global $list;
    $list[0]['QTY'] = '2'; //or this 2 value can be taken from user using jquery 
    }

my_function();
```

Comment: This would be just for the item at index 0. how could i do this for an item at a different index selected by the user?

Answer (score 1):

For the script that this submits to, you want to loop through each item in the cart_array session and find it by that ID then change the quantity for that item.

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $item){
   if($item['ID'] == $_POST['ID']){
     $_SESSION['cart_array'][$index]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your quantity value from the user like this

```
<?php
$_SESSION['Cart_array'] = array(
                1 => array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                )
            );

$_SESSION['Cart_array'][1]['QTY']=30;//Relaces the quantity from 1 to 30
```

Comment: This would be just for the item at index 1. how could i do this for an item at a different index selected by the user?

Comment: How are you assigning `1` ? as the key ? Can you post the code logic ?

Comment: if (!isset($_SESSION['Cart_array']) || count($_SESSION['Cart_array']) < 1) { //check if cart session is not set or empty
            $_SESSION['Cart_array'] = array(
                1 => array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                )
            );
        } else {
                array_push($_SESSION['Cart_array'], array(
                    "ID" => $pid,
                    "QTY" => 1
                ));
            
        } //end else